How to disallow any application from inhibiting power management?
At some point my laptop has stopped reliably enabling lockscreen when idle.
It will lock if I run the command manually (xflock4).
Running a command I found elsewhere:
dbus-send --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement --print-reply=literal \
    /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit \
    org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.GetInhibitors

currently shows:
   array [
      firefox      firefox   ]

which corresponds to the power management panel messages:
firefox is currently inhibiting power management
firefox is currently inhibiting power management

However this does not change even when firefox is not running.
Presumably, at some point firefox inhibited power management but, erroneously, this is never being released.
How do I either:

Block any misbehaving application (in this example, firefox) from inhibiting power management?
Or, manually force inhibits to be released?

I see there is a file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy which might be relevant for the first option, but I don't know how to use it.
For the second, perhaps there is code I can run, but I don't know anything about the API or how to use it aside from finding https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/ and I don't see anything that indicates a lock can be forcefully released by a third party.

"However this does not change even when firefox is not running." Did you properly quit Firefox, or did you merely kill the process?

@user535733 firefox is an example. I want to know how to resolve the situation for any application. But for the sake of argument, let's assume I kill -9 firefox and the wakelock(?) is left behind. How do I remove it programmatically? I don't want to have to quit everything else I'm running and logout/reboot. Better yet, how do I block applications from setting wakelocks in the first place?

The URL i obsolete, use https://systemd.io/INHIBITOR_LOCKS/. And use systemd-inhibit to take locks or list active locks from the command line.

@MatsK I've logged out since my post, but my recollection is that systemd-inhibit --list did not show the firefox items. your new url is linked from the one I gave - neither one shows how to break a lock

I started hitting this issue as well some weeks ago. I suppose there has to be related with an upgrade or similar. systemd-inhibit --list shows libxfce4ui      block, which is what I suspect it's blocking the system to suspend. The dbus-send command from the OP shows firefox to me as well, and the power management panel too.
